# How to disable windows firewall for all networked machines using the command line in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall, windows-server-2016

I am currently building a Hyper-V lab consisting of a DC and multiple networked VMs, using Windows Server 2016.  I'd like to completely disable the windows firewall for all existing and newly created VMs.

The best way that I've found to do this so far is via Group Policy for the Domain Profile.  Then set `Windows Firewall: Protect all network connections` to `disabled`. What I would like to do is to have a way of scripting this out (using Powershell if possible).

I've found that by performing the above steps in the GUI, it creates a few entries in the registry:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile`

In each of those entries, there is a property called `EnableFirewall` which is set to `0`. So I tried creating all of this using Powershell like this:

```
New-Item -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft" -name WindowsFirewall 
New-Item -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall" -name DomainProfile
New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile" -name EnableFirewall -value 0 -PropertyType DWord -Force
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working, so there must be something else that I'm missing.

Does anybody know how to completely disable the windows firewall for all networked machines using the command line in Windows Server 2016?

Comment: I think the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile` and also the `domain profile`. both you have to change. You can use `set-item` to set the registry property. and for value use `set-itemproperty`

Comment: Just a note: both `Set-NetFirewallProfile` and `netsh` answers will disable the firewall for existing computers, but they will need to be re-run to update newly created computers. Group Policy on the other hand will apply to any computers that are newly created (assuming targeting is at domain root)

Comment: I second @JamesC. so basically, you need to use either invoke-command or a startup script or a psexec or group policy so that while adding it to the domain only it will enforce

Comment: @Andy Just wondering your reason for not wanting to use GP when it does exactly what you want?

Comment: Thank you all for your time.  GP does exactly what I want, I would just like a way of modifying GP using Powershell.  I'm building a lab from scratch, and I'm looking to script as much of it as possible rather than using the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the Windows-Firewall for your domain-computers through computer-startup-script is not a great solution in my opinion.
You should definetly use Group Policy for this task.

> GP does exactly what I want, I would just like a way of modifying GP using Powershell. I'm building a lab from scratch, and I'm looking to script as much of it as possible rather than using the gui.

I am not completely sure, what you are trying to achive.
You have created a lab now and I think you are trying to script a complete automatic built-up for future use. Is this correct?

If yes, then my solution is maybe what you are looking for:

1. Create a new GPO in your lab named "Firewall-Settings" for example.
2. Make all of your needed FireWall-Settings to the new GPO.
3. In Group Policy Editor open the main-node named „Group Policy Objects“. (important) Find the newly created GPO, right-click it and select "Backup":

[image: GPO Backup]

4. Save the GPO-backup to a folder. (folder must exist)

[image: GPO Backup to folder]

5. The GPO is beeing saved and named like on the screenshot below (GUID):

[image: Saved GPO in File-System]

That's it for the preparation. Now you maybe want to script the creation of the GPO with Powershell for future use and import the backup to obtain it's settings in a new environment:

```
New-GPO -Name "FireWall-Settings" | New-GPLink -Target "DC=mydomain,DC=local" # distinguishedName of Target-OU
Import-GPO -Path $PathtoGPOBackup -TargetName "FireWall-Settings" -BackupGpoName "FireWall-Settings"
```

The Script creates a GPO in the new environment with the name "FireWall-Settings" and links it to the target-OU.
After that you import the settings of the backup-GPO. All the domain-members in scope of the GPO will get the Windows-Firewall configured automatically.

Now the process is documented and fully automatic, if this is, what you are looking for.

Kind regards

Comment: Thanks Walhalla, that does the job for me.  I'm still really surprised that there isn't more Powershell to modify group policy, but this is a good workaround.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

open cmd prompt with elevated mode and run this:

```
netsh -r ComputerName -u Username -p Password -c advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

If you want to do it for all the machines. Get all the ad computers using `get-adcomputer`. Run a foreach loop and put the variable istead of computername.

If you have the domain admin creds, then you are good to go with this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ranadip

Whilst this might work for all the networked machines that currently exist, I'd like to apply it to any new ones that I create in the future too.  When I edit the Default Domain Profile using the GUI, it applies the policy to all existing machines - but also any new ones that get added to the domain in future.  I don't think your method would do this, and it would only work for existing machines. 

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: For newly added system you have to have a startup script for the new ones or you have to push it through group policy. by any means you have to run certain set of commands , either locally or remotely. For that once the system is added into the domain , you can do that. best way again is the group policy enforcing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the profile you want to disable, specify profiles (public, domain, private) using the `-Name` parameter. To disable all profiles for a networked machine, where `$computerName` array is the hostname of your DC, PC etc:

```
    $computerName = 'DC1, PC1, MS1'
    Invoke-Command -Computername $computerName -ScriptBlock {
        Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name Domain, Public, Private -Enabled False
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jelphy.  It made changes to my DC, but those changes are not applied to the other machines on the network.

Comment: @Andy The `$computerName` parameter can take an array of machines. `$computerName = 'DC1, DC2, PC1'` - this will make the changes to the other computers.

Comment: Thanks Jelphy.  Ideally I'd like it to apply the changes to any new machines that are added to the network as well - I don't want to have to run this every time I add a new machine to the network.  I'm really surprised that there isn't a way of modifying group policy in Powershell! Thanks for your time